Load a SharePoint page without login in Android using Using Microsoft Graph API
I could able to generate the access_token using tenant_id, client_id, and client_secret.
Using the access_token, I would like to load the SharePoint page(Ex:XYZ.sharepoint.com/home.aspx) to WebView Android.
Is it possible to load a SharePoint page directly to WebView Android? If yes, what is the syntax to create a Graph API client to get the SharePoint Page?
It would be really helpful, if you share the code structure of it.
I tried this request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site-id with the access_token
and I got a json response as,
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",
"createdDateTime": "2023-08-31T19:14:43.683Z",
"description": "",
"id": "XYZ.sharepoint.com,e739f562-c6bb-341d-9b36-f33f1d5bcde2,725gkb4b-7dd3-4211-9f3a-f450dce166c9",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-04-16T13:40:58Z",
"name": "ScanscapeSpotlight",
"webUrl": "https://XYZ.sharepoint.com/sites/home",
"displayName": "ABC",
"root": {},
"siteCollection": {
"hostname": "XYZ.sharepoint.com"
}
}
Have tried these webview.loadUrl() and webview.loadData() to load response but it didnt load the page
